# SpringBatch read() function in ItemReader class return type is String and Want to return FlatFileItemReader<String> , How should i Do it?

Tags: spring-batch

My Springbatch Configuration class have following job :

```
public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
  Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("sampleSetp")
  .<String, String>chunk(10)
  .reader(new Reader())
  .writer(new Writer())
  .build();
}
```

And My Reader class is :

```
public class Reader implements ItemReader<String> {
  @Override
  public String read() {
  FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<String>();
  reader.setResource(someResource);
  reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
  
  **return reader; //This should be string, but i have FlatFileItemReader<String> type.**
  }
}
```

I am doing some work on reader(FlatFileItemReader) and want to return to job this reader but read() return type is String.

How should i send this reader to job present in BathConfig?

NOTE: IF i make do this FlatFileItemReader processing in springConfig file and pass it to job there only then it is working.
ex:

```
Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("sampleSetp")
  .<String, String>chunk(10)
  .reader(flatFileReader())
  .write()
  .build();
```

where flatFileReader() is :

```
public FlatFileItemReader<String> flatFileReader(){
 ...
 return FlatFileItemReader<String> type
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SpringBatch read() function in ItemReader class return type is String and Want to return FlatFileItemReader , How should i Do it?

The `read` method should return the actual item (a String in your case) and not another reader. If you want a custom reader that delegates to a `FlatFileItemReader`, you can do something like:

```
public class Reader implements ItemReader<String> {
   private FlatFileItemReader<String> delegate;
   public Reader(FlatFileItemReader<String> delegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   public String read() {
      return delegate.read();
   }
}
```